# How to make the footer design responsive in Bootstrap v2.0.1?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm using Bootstrap v2.0.1 for my website.

I'm using following files from Bootstrap in my design :

1. bootstrap.css
2. example-fixed-layout.css
3. bootstrap-responsive.css
4. signin.css

Now I've a footer HTML code which is working fine on all browsers on all PCs and laptops.

The issue I'm facing is on Tablets and Smartphones. The footer doesn't remain responsive at all. How should I make this footer responsive for all browsers and all devices of variant sizes?

Can someone please help me in this regard? Following is my HTML code for footer:

```
<footer style="background-color:#000"  id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span3 top-buffer-footer">
        <p> &copy; 2014 PROJECT NAME</p>
      </div>
      <div align="center" class="span7 top-buffer-footer">
        <a  href="#">About Us</a> |
        <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a> |
        <a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a>
      </div>
      <div class="span2 top-buffer-footer">
        <a style="float:right"  href="#">Powered By Company Name</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need any further information regarding the issue I'm facing please do let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The footer doesn't remain responsive at all? meaning..?you posted html, but the problem would mostly lie in your css(gave files names- its of no help). plz post your css code or better make a fiddle

Comment: You can change the classes to .row-fluid and .container-fluid, then .remove the float:right and put that in a min-width media query where it's supposed to go.

Comment: You should upgrade to Bootstrap v2.3.2; it includes numerous big fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Try give it a height and width then apply a margin 0 to center it.
It will then move onaccord to the screen size.

Otherwise said, use inspect element to check what is causing this to your code.
Or visit http://getbootstrap.com/components/ for responsive pre-defined containers.